# for convention in which folder should I place no-installable applications?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, application

I've just downloaded Eclipse Neon and I don't know in which folder should I place it, also I want to create an entry on Gnome's menu, how can I achieve that?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but it solves the underlying problem: in Fedora 24 and 25, `dnf install eclipse` installs [Eclipse Neon](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/eclipse/about.html) in a nicely-packaged way, with GNOME integration etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's considered good practice to install "local" programs that you've downloaded (and possibly compiled yourself) into `/usr/local`. The directories beneath `/usr/local` should mirror the usually directories, so you have `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib`, etc. Many applications also check the `/usr/local` hierarchy, so downloaded programs and libraries integrate with your other applications.

I have a lot of these programs, and to make installing and uninstalling them easier, I use a program called [stow](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) (usually available as a package) that creates symlinks. So I have a directory `/usr/local/stow`, and all installable files (say for a package `eclipse_neon`) go into `/usr/local/stow/eclipse_neon`, with `bin/` etc. directories as appropriate. Then I can use `stow` to "install" and "uninstall" the package into the `/usr/local/` hierarchy, and just do a `rm -rf /usr/local/stow/eclipse_neon` if I want to get rid of the package completely.

But that's only one way to manage `/usr/local`, there are other ways.

To make an entry into Gnome's menu, you need to put a [desktop file](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) in a location where Gnome can find it.